# How to start Tomcat as non root on boot

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu

How to start Tomcat under different user on boot? I've tried the following command but it prompts for password.

```
su -c "/etc/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start" tomcat
```

I'm using Tomcat 7.0.40 and Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: unless you're running that from a root shell, you WILL be prompted for the password of the account you're trying to `su` to. e.g. if you're running as `fred`, and you do `su sally`, then you'll get prompted for sally's password.

Comment: Tomcat will not run as root if you installed it through apt unless you configured it to.

Comment: I use tar installation of tomcat. Try to edit /etc/rc.local and add a command like yours to that file. It works in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JSVC](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html), read [Tomcat JSVC manual](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html#Unix_daemon) or simply install package [tomcat7](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/tomcat7).

Answer (score 2):

Create a config file `tomcat.conf` and put it under `/etc/init`

`/etc/init` contains configuration files used by Upstart

the `tomcat.conf` will look like the following lines (**Note:** Replace `JAVA_HOME` and `CATALINA_HOME` with your own ):

```
description "Tomcat Server"

  start on runlevel [2345]
  stop on runlevel [!2345]
  respawn
  respawn limit 10 5

  # run as non privileged user 
  # add user with this command:
  ## adduser --system --ingroup www-data --home /opt/apache-tomcat apache-tomcat
  # Ubuntu 12.04: (use 'exec sudo -u apache-tomcat' when using 10.04)
  setuid apache-tomcat
  setgid www-data

  # adapt paths - Replace with your Paths:
  env JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_13/
  env CATALINA_HOME=/home/mohammed/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/

  # adapt java options to suit your needs:
  env JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"

  exec $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh run

  # cleanup temp directory after stop
  post-stop script 
    rm -rf $CATALINA_HOME/temp/*
  end script
```